# Difficults to connect a vue and js file to display

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on building a vuejs website, and I was making a count button to increase/decrease, but it is not displaying it.

This is what I've for the JS file

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// eslint-disable-next-line no-new
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0,
    count6: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count += 1
    },
    decrement() {
      this.count = Math.max(0, this.count - 1)
    },
    increment6() {
      this.count6 += 1
    },
    decrement6() {
      this.count6 = Math.max(0, this.count6 - 1)
    },
  },
})
```

And inside the vue file I've this part of the code to display it

```
    <div class="pl-20">
      <div>
        <h1 class="title text-white">How often do you fly per year?</h1>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-4">
          <button
            class="countbutton"
            :disabled="count === 0"
            @click="decrement"
          >
            &#8722;
          </button>
          <div class="text-white">{{ count }}</div>
          <button class="countbutton" @click="increment">&#43;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pt-5">
        <h1 class="title text-white">How many flights over 6 hours?</h1>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-4">
          <button
            class="countbutton"
            :disabled="count6 === 0"
            @click="decrement6"
          >
            &#8722;
          </button>
          <div class="text-white">{{ count6 }}</div>
          <button class="countbutton" @click="increment6">&#43;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And when displaying it, the count doesn't work properly

[image]

And when I check the inspect, the {{ count }} doesn't appear.

[image]

I just don't know what I'm missing to connect the JS with vue to make the counter work properly

Comment: You have a single variable for both questions, and clicking the plus decrements while clicking minus increments. Are you asking how to fix these issues? Because the JS is absolutely connected with your template, you just need to implement two very basic fixes to your code.

Comment: Here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/o5a1t87q/

Comment: Hey hey @ChrisG, thank you so much for your time and effort, just saw that you did an amazing thing to help me but I think that is something wrong on my setup, don't because I copy/paste it your code and still not displaying, and also I had to fix the code into differente way (just dont why), I think is the vue setup I've on the VScode

Comment: I'll update here with the code that the VScode proposed me to fix it inside the vue file to you take a look

Comment: So are you saying the counter buttons don't work at all? Are you getting any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: I don't receive any error message, that looks weird for me. Just saw the inspect of my website, and doesn't appear the "{{ count }} part

Comment: Hm, there has to be *some* type of connection, or you'd see `{{ count }}` on the page. No idea what's happening though.

Comment: Thank you so much for effort @ChrisG, I'll try to restart to check if the issues stop

Comment: Hello @ChrisG, I had to make a change and use the Single file component to make it work, but thanks for you effort helping with the count part, amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of [@Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) on the site of the count function and the [@user3094755](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3094755/user3094755), I was able to find the solution to put all inside one file component on VUE.

I just added this part inside my vue file

```
<script>
export default {
  el: '#app',
  name: 'TravelOptions',
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      count1: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count += 1
    },
    decrement() {
      this.count = Math.max(0, this.count - 1)
    },
    increment1() {
      this.count1 += 1
    },
    decrement1() {
      this.count1 = Math.max(0, this.count1 - 1)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this issue identified ( ie, the same counter is being used twice ) there's no issue with your HTML / Javascript.  It's likley the build system you are using is not set up correctly.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-new
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count += 1
    },
    decrement() {
      this.count -= 1
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="pt-5 pl-20">
      <div>
        <h1 class="title text-white">How often do you fly per year?</h1>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-4">
          <button class="countbutton" @click="increment">&#8722;</button>
          <div class="text-white">{{ count }}</div>
          <button class="countbutton" @click="decrement">&#43;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pt-5">
        <h1 class="title text-white">How many flights over 6 hours?</h1>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-4">
          <button class="countbutton" @click="increment">&#8722;</button>
          <div class="text-white">{{ count }}</div>
          <button class="countbutton" @click="decrement">&#43;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello @user3094755, thanks for your time but for me still doesn't work, just don't why

Comment: As you can see it works in the above snippet and your code is the same, so it's not a problem with the code. Are you building you App using vue CLI / Single File Components ?

Comment: No, my App has multiple components, I based myself to install the project basing on the nuxtjs with tailwind (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs), don't know if this can help

Comment: So if you're using Nuxtjs then it's Vue Single File Components.  Have you looked at the format for single file components ?

Comment: Yeah, I check it out and looks that I need to put the content from the JS file inside the vue on the script part, thanks, I'll check it out to move and put on the right format

Comment: thank you so much @user3094755, now worked put the JS content inside the vue, thanks a again for the tip